# How to verify custom key-pair value in a JWT body

Tags: java, jose4j

I'm implementing a JWT solution and I'm using jose4j. I'm facing the problem that I have non-standard/custom key-pair value (such as *"application-id" : 124123*) in the body of the JWT that I want to verify, but I can't find the way to do it in Jose4J. I'd not mind an example.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is from https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWT%20Examples#markdown-header-producing-and-consuming-a-signed-jwt and was modified slightly to show 'application-id' being included when creating the JWT and extracted after validation. You can verify the value at that point. Or you could also implement your own https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/latest/org/jose4j/jwt/consumer/Validator.html and set up your `JwtConsomer` with it when using the builder https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.7.4/org/jose4j/jwt/consumer/JwtConsumerBuilder.html#registerValidator(org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.Validator)

```
        //
        // This example demonstrates producing and consuming a signed JWT
        //

        // Generate an RSA key pair, which will be used for signing and verification of the JWT, wrapped in a JWK
        RsaJsonWebKey rsaJsonWebKey = RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);

        // Give the JWK a Key ID (kid), which is just the polite thing to do
        rsaJsonWebKey.setKeyId("k1");

        // Create the Claims, which will be the content of the JWT
        JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
        claims.setIssuer("Issuer");  // who creates the token and signs it
        claims.setAudience("Audience"); // to whom the token is intended to be sent
        claims.setExpirationTimeMinutesInTheFuture(10); // time when the token will expire (10 minutes from now)
        claims.setGeneratedJwtId(); // a unique identifier for the token
        claims.setIssuedAtToNow();  // when the token was issued/created (now)
        claims.setNotBeforeMinutesInThePast(2); // time before which the token is not yet valid (2 minutes ago)
        claims.setSubject("subject"); // the subject/principal is whom the token is about
        claims.setClaim("email","mail@example.com"); // additional claims/attributes about the subject can be added
        List<String> groups = Arrays.asList("group-one", "other-group", "group-three");
        claims.setStringListClaim("groups", groups); // multi-valued claims work too and will end up as a JSON array
        claims.setClaim("application-id", 124123);

        // A JWT is a JWS and/or a JWE with JSON claims as the payload.
        // In this example it is a JWS so we create a JsonWebSignature object.
        JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();

        // The payload of the JWS is JSON content of the JWT Claims
        jws.setPayload(claims.toJson());

        // The JWT is signed using the private key
        jws.setKey(rsaJsonWebKey.getPrivateKey());

        // Set the Key ID (kid) header because it's just the polite thing to do.
        // We only have one key in this example but a using a Key ID helps
        // facilitate a smooth key rollover process
        jws.setKeyIdHeaderValue(rsaJsonWebKey.getKeyId());

        // Set the signature algorithm on the JWT/JWS that will integrity protect the claims
        jws.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_USING_SHA256);

        // Sign the JWS and produce the compact serialization or the complete JWT/JWS
        // representation, which is a string consisting of three dot ('.') separated
        // base64url-encoded parts in the form Header.Payload.Signature
        // If you wanted to encrypt it, you can simply set this jwt as the payload
        // of a JsonWebEncryption object and set the cty (Content Type) header to "jwt".
        String jwt = jws.getCompactSerialization();


        // Now you can do something with the JWT. Like send it to some other party
        // over the clouds and through the interwebs.
        System.out.println("JWT: " + jwt);


        // Use JwtConsumerBuilder to construct an appropriate JwtConsumer, which will
        // be used to validate and process the JWT.
        // The specific validation requirements for a JWT are context dependent, however,
        // it typically advisable to require a (reasonable) expiration time, a trusted issuer, and
        // and audience that identifies your system as the intended recipient.
        // If the JWT is encrypted too, you need only provide a decryption key or
        // decryption key resolver to the builder.
        JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
                .setRequireExpirationTime() // the JWT must have an expiration time
                .setAllowedClockSkewInSeconds(30) // allow some leeway in validating time based claims to account for clock skew
                .setRequireSubject() // the JWT must have a subject claim
                .setExpectedIssuer("Issuer") // whom the JWT needs to have been issued by
                .setExpectedAudience("Audience") // to whom the JWT is intended for
                .setVerificationKey(rsaJsonWebKey.getKey()) // verify the signature with the public key
                .setJwsAlgorithmConstraints( // only allow the expected signature algorithm(s) in the given context
                        AlgorithmConstraints.ConstraintType.PERMIT, AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_USING_SHA256) // which is only RS256 here
                .build(); // create the JwtConsumer instance

        try
        {
            //  Validate the JWT and process it to the Claims
            JwtClaims jwtClaims = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(jwt);
            System.out.println("JWT validation succeeded! " + jwtClaims);

            long appId = jwtClaims.getClaimValue("application-id", Long.class);
            System.out.println(appId);
        }
        catch (InvalidJwtException e)
        {
            // InvalidJwtException will be thrown, if the JWT failed processing or validation in anyway.
            // Hopefully with meaningful explanations(s) about what went wrong.
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT! " + e);

            // Programmatic access to (some) specific reasons for JWT invalidity is also possible
            // should you want different error handling behavior for certain conditions.

            // Whether or not the JWT has expired being one common reason for invalidity
            if (e.hasExpired())
            {
                System.out.println("JWT expired at " + e.getJwtContext().getJwtClaims().getExpirationTime());
            }

            // Or maybe the audience was invalid
            if (e.hasErrorCode(ErrorCodes.AUDIENCE_INVALID))
            {
                System.out.println("JWT had wrong audience: " + e.getJwtContext().getJwtClaims().getAudience());
            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Custom key-pair
String publicKeyStr = "encoded public key";
String privateKeyStr = "encoded private key";
KeyPair keyPair = RSAUtil.parser(publicKeyStr, privateKeyStr);

RsaJsonWebKey rsaJsonWebKey = RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);
rsaJsonWebKey.setPrivateKey(keyPair.getPrivate());

JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
// ...

JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();
jws.setPayload(claims.toJson());
jws.setKey(rsaJsonWebKey.getPrivateKey());
jws.setKeyIdHeaderValue(rsaJsonWebKey.getKeyId());
jws.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_USING_SHA256);
String jwt = jws.getCompactSerialization();

JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
    // ...
    .setVerificationKey(keyPair.getPublic())
    // ...
    .build();

JwtClaims jwtClaims = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(jwt);
```